# GNU Readline linked with default Python on FreeBSD, OpenBSD?

Tags: python, gnu, freebsd, openbsd

How easy is it to get a Python that isn't linked to GNU Readline on FreeBSD or OpenBSD? Is GNU Readline the default for Python readline-like support on these systems? If so, is it easy to remove this dependency?

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD, libreadline is part of the base system (unless you've rebuilt that without GNU). Python loads that dynamically;

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so:
    libreadline.so.8 => /lib/libreadline.so.8 (0x801206000)
    libthr.so.3 => /lib/libthr.so.3 (0x801445000)
    libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x80084a000)
    libncurses.so.8 => /lib/libncurses.so.8 (0x801668000)
```

There is no configure option to remove it from the Python build.